# Resize UILabel according to text

Tags: objective-c

I want to resize my `UILabel` according to the UILabel text. The code I have does not make the 
UILabel according to its width..

My current code:

```
UILabel *textLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 158, self.view.bounds.size.width-40, 550)];
textLabel2.text = textString;
textLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17];
textLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
[textLabel2 sizeToFit];
[self.scroller addSubview:textLabel2];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//set label backgroundColor so you can see the label width changes according to text
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//edit you label text
[label setText:@"very longgggg text"];

//get width of you text and set you font size to 17.0
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]].width;

//set you label frame
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, width, 30);

//add label to you view
[self.view addSubview:label];
```